# Vectorize and separate find operation in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vectorization

I will try to explain what I am seeking through an example.

Suppose I have an 3x4 2D matrix like this:

1 0 0 0
1 1 1 0
0 0 1 1

This is the matlab matrix that can be produced by:

```
x = [1 0 0 0; 1 1 1 0; 0 0 1 1]
```

Now if I execute a command like this:

```
[~, y] = find(x([1 2], :) == 1)
```

y would be a vector that contains the column indices in rows 1 and 2 that have a value of 1. Specifically, for this example:

```
y = [1 1 2 3]
```

However, what I wish to accomplish is to separate the nonzero columns in every element of the input array (here [1 2]) without having to iterate over the elements of this input array (in vectorized way).

So I wish to get an output like this:

```
y = [[1] [1 2 3]]
```

Not strictly in this format but in any separated form.

Comment: Note that `[[1] [1 2 3]]` is `[1 1 2 3]`. You probably want `{[1],[1 2 3]}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question right, you want to group it according to the row. Then maintain the row:

```
[r, y] = find(x([1 2], :) == 1)
```

Then you could use `accumarray`

```
y2 = accumarray(r,y,[max(r),1],@(x)({x}))
```

For your example it returns

```
y2 = {[1],[1 2 3]}
```

Comment: Nice use of `accumarray`!

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thank :)